# full path of a folder in c#

Tags: c#

i need to get the full folder path in a windows project using c#.I tried with path.getFulPath(filename).bt it returns the application path+filename.how can i get the actual path like "D:\eclipse_files\ads_data"?

Answer (score 2):

A relative path such as `myfile.txt` is always resolved in relation to the current working directory.

In your case the current working directory seems to be `D:\eclipse_files\ads_data` so your relative file path gets resolved to `D:\eclipse_files\ads_data\myfile.txt` when you call `Path.GetFullPath`.

To solve the problem, either make sure that you start with an absolute path from the beginning, or, that your working directory is set correctly.

You can get/set the working directory using the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` and `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you're looking for this:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
```

Comment: I WILL MAKE IT CLESR.MY APPLICATION IS SAVED IN D:\WindowsExplorer.AND PATH.GETFULLPATH("DOC") OR Path.GetDirectoryName("DOC") RETURNS "".actulai it should return "D:\myDoc\\doc".how can i solve this proble.i am doig a windows explorer and i want to get the full path.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you have a filename, for example 'doc.txt', and you want to have a method to return the full path of this file regardless of where the application runs from?

If this is what you ask it is not possible. Have you considered that there might be several files called 'doc.txt' on your harddrives?

The best you can hope to do it to search all harddrives, and return a list of all files found with the same name, but that will just be ridicously slow.